Find Eigenvalues of ODE45 Solution MATLAB
I have the following non-linear ODE:

I have the following ODE45 solution:
fun = @(t,X)odefun(X,K,C,M,F(t),resSize); 
[t_ode,X_answer] = ode45(fun,tspan,X_0); 

The input matrices are stiffness K(X), damping C, mass M, and force F. resSize is the total number of masses in the system.
I would like to find the system's eigenvalues using either the Jacobian matrix, transfer function, or any other viable method.
I have tried using:
[vector,lambda,condition_number] = polyeig(K(X_answer),C,M);

This is tricky since my K matrix is a function handle of X. In other words, K=@(X). X represents a displacement vector of each mass in the system (x_1(t),x_2(t),...x_resSize(t)), where resSize is the total number of masses. My X_answer matrix is a double with dimensions of t_ode by resSize, where each row is the displacement vector of each mass in double form. Is there some way to substitute X_answer into my function handle for K so I can use polyeig()? If not, how would I go about finding my system's transfer function or Jacobian matrix so that I can find it's eigenvalues?

Without knowing the exact form of your equation, based on your description, I suppose you have something like:
[M]{x''}+[C]{x'} + [K(x)]{x} = F(t)
Since this system of equations is nonlinear, the eigenvalues can be estimated based on a expansion around each x estimated from the output of the ode45 function.
Since ode45 integrates a system of first order equations, you probably have introduced a change of variables, to write the above system as a system of first order. In state space form, this is
{y'} = [A]{y} + b(t), with {y} = {x ; x'}
So, the output of the ode function contains the displacements {x} and the velocities {x'}.
If you want to estimate the eigenvalues for each x on the output, you could do
for ii=1:length(t_ode)
    [X,e] = polyeig(K(X_answer(ii,1:end/2),C,M)
end


Does polyeig() only apply for homogenous EOMs? In other words, am I finding the eigenvalues of my ODE assuming that F(t)=0 when using polyeig()? @Thales

Yes. The general solution is Xh(t) + Xp(t), wherein Xh is the solution to the associated homogenous equation, while Xp is a particular equation. The homogeneous solution, for  linear differential equations, is found solving the associated eigenvalue problem.

I'm trying to get the transfer function for this system. You were correct when you assumed that I did a change of variables. What is b(t) in the 1st order SS you wrote?

b(t) is the excitation vector, with proper dimension. tipically,  {b(t)} = [zeros(n_gdl,1) ; M\f(t)]
